# Silverlight listbox question

Tags: silverlight, listbox, itemssource

I'm using `listBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.Persons`, which is a collection of persons. The listbox shows the actual object names when I would like it to show the first name of each person object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

use Listboxes ItemTemplate.
something like this.

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the method of binding specified by the other response, you could simply bind it as follows:

```
listBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.Persons.Select(d => new { FirstName });
```

Comment: I don't like much that way of achieving the requested functionality, as it will replace every occurence of the Person instances in the ListBox by the FirstName content. For instance, you probably don't want this behavior for the SelectedItem Property..

Comment: I agree, but if the Listbox is truly disconnected from the source data and your value is the value you wish to extract this is an option.  The binding approach is of course the best way to go, but this option demonstrates the ability to filter out to anonymous types in order to meet your needs.

Comment: Great discussion guys, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the dedicated ["DisplayMemberPath" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), which do exactly what you want easily without any side effects (nor additional markup):

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" />
```

For more complicated item representations, use templates (see below).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ToString() method of the Persons object so that it display the first name of the person.